# Not able to run jmeter script in non gui mode. It is recorded using blazemeter and running on jmeter 5 version

Tags: macos, terminal, jmeter

When Running the JMX script from terminal on MAC IN NON-GUI Mode, it returns an error saying "Could not open"

Below are the things i have tried : 
1) jmeter -n -t "ABSOLUTE PATH.jmx" -l ABSOLUTE-PATH for results.jtl
2) Set the jmeter path and tried again.

I get the same error every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can run the recording using JMeter as [BlazeMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium) exports recorded scripts in YAML format suitable for [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool

[image]

So you can run it using Taurus tool as

```
bzt test-Combined-JMeter-and-Selenium.yaml
```

---

If you want to convert it to "vanilla" JMeter - execute the following command:

```
bzt test-Combined-JMeter-and-Selenium.yaml -gui
```

JMeter GUI will open where you will be able to modify and save generated JMeter script as .jmx file which can be executed using JMeter.